# Replace video with an image on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

How do I replace a video with an image if the video is missing a source?

```
<div id="gameImage"><img id="img" src=""></div>
<div id="gameTrailer">
    <video autoplay loop width="960" height="540" id="video">
        <source src="" id="gameTrailer_window">
    </video>
</div>
```

The source to the video is appended via AJAX like this:

```
var videoSrc = data.gameTrailer;
var video_block = $('#video');
video_block.load();
$("#video").find("#gameTrailer_window").attr("src", videoSrc)
```

..but in some cases, `var videoSrc` will equal null, meaning that no video will show up. So I figured an `onError`-function displaying an image instead (which will always have a source available) would work, but a video element without source does not seem to be returning an error, therefor the following function:

```
$("#video").error(function () { 
    $(this).hide(); 
    $("#gameImage").find("#img").attr("src", data.gameImage)
});
```

..will not fire. It might be something off with the code, I'm not 100% certain.

Any sort of nudge in the right direction will be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you check the condition in first function instead of writing another function

```
if(videoSrc!=null){
  $("#video").find("#gameTrailer_window").attr("src", videoSrc)
} else {
  $("#gameImage").find("#img").attr("src", data.gameImage);
}
```

> If var is not null then video src will change else image src will change.

Comment: Because I'm no good at this really. Thanks, although that did solve one problem, something else came up. The src for the videos are replaced in the code (inspect element), but the video doesn't change / the video is just a white field.